# Sharepoint Randomly Show Wrong Logged in User

Tags: sharepoint

I`m creating a Web-Part for SharePoint 2013 and inside it I need to display User full name with Picture so i use this code:

```
SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Site);
UserProfileManager upManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
loginUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
UserProfile userProfile = upManager.GetUserProfile(loginUser);
```

now i access the info using:

```
userProfile[PropertyConstants.PictureUrl].Value
userProfile[PropertyConstants.FirstName].Value
userProfile[PropertyConstants.LastName].Value
```

Now this works, However randomly it reports random wrong users, so sometimes the webpart shows username that is different than the one showing in the built-in MasterPage, honestly the Built-in is always showing the right one!,

problem is i cant reproduce this issue, it happens randomly,

my questions are:

1. Is that the right way to get these info?
2. How is SharePoint built-in Master-Page is getting these info?
3. Do I need to execute the mentioned code with Elevation ?
4. Any clue why this is happening ?

Comment: How many sites ? how many site collections ? Maybe you get the wrong web, Try with the specified site guid, check this: using(SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb(guidWebsite))
{
    SPUser oUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
}

Comment: isn't this supposed to get me the current web ?SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Site);

Comment: Maybe the wrong users is the Farm Admin or Service user ? Do you use **RunWithElevatedPrivilege** ?

Comment: No i don't use RunWithElevatedPrivilege, and the wrong user is random, I got some feedback from end users with two different wrong users !

Comment: Have you used the menu function **change user**, sometimes sharepoint did me the same thing, changing user do not refreshed the user displayed on the upper right.

Comment: Actually the upper right is always right, problem is with the label inside the Web Part....

Comment: its been long time, but I am getting the same issue, how did you fix it?